# Change ListView items order when working with item source

Tags: wpf, listview, itemsource

I have this collection:

```
ObservableCollection<MyData> Files;
```

This collection is full of objects and i put this list inside my `ListView`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
```

Now when my application do the work vai `Parallel.Foreach` (via different threads)
i want to be able to cange the order inside my `ListView`.
I have try something like that:

```
private void MoveItem()
{
    var itemToMove = lvPcapFiles.Items[3];
    lvPcapFiles.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    lvPcapFiles.Items.Insert(0, itemToMove);
}
```

And when try to use it i have this `InvalidOperationException` error:

> Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify
>   elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Comment: The exception message clearly says what to do: sort the `Files` collection instead of `lvPcapFiles.Items`. Otherwise you may use a `SortDescription` in conjuction with a `CollectionViewSource`.

Comment: If i move item from 1 place to another inside my collection it reflect my ListView ?

Comment: Sure, that's why you have an ObservableCollection.